# Nextjs with asset prefix

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

Nextjs server pages is working when using asset prefix in Production with proxy but pages are not loading when using asset prefix in development when accessing:

http://localhost:port/prefix/pagename

While in Production using:

http://localhost/prefix/pageName

Can you suggest how should we approach to this problem?

Comment: could you give more details to your setup? Like what are you using for your proxy and what is it's setting? Maybe a screenshot of the 404 errors in your browser?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet on how you display an asset?